# SQL Server : update replace statement - code fail or bug?

Tags: sql-server, replace, str-replace

I am trying to replace all letters in string with "L" and all the number with letter "N" in SQL Server 2014.

I am using following statement:

```
update my_table 
set column2 = replace(column1, 'a', 'L');

update my_table 
set column2 = replace(column1, 'b', 'L');

update my_table 
set column2 = replace(column1, '1', 'N');
etc. etc.
```

The problem is, when I execute the query I get that column2 = column1 e.g. abc(column1) = abc(column2)

If I query only one commit e.g. `update my_table set column2 = replace(column1, 'a', 'L');` then it works fine, it replaces all A to L.

I tried to excute this query with Sqlite and tested it with smaller database and it works just fine, but i would really need to make this work in mssql.

I would really highly appreciate any support with this question.

I have just started to use SQL Server and I still trying to adopt to changes.

p.s. `column2 varchar(64)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you have a fixed length data in your column_1, in case it's fixed you can use the following:

```
declare @Index int=1

while(@Index<= your data length here)
begin
    update my_table 
    set column_2 = REPLACE(substring(column_1, @Index, 1),
                           case 
                              when ASCII(substring(column_1, @Index, 1)) between 48 and 57 
                                then 'N' 
                                else 'L' 
                           end)

    set @Index = @Index + 1
end
```

Comment: Need to distinguish between first update and the others, cause the others should update column_2 and not 1

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think happens in your code. Consider the `column2` to be `'123456'` and `column1` to be `'ab1'`. So then you run the first update:

```
update my_table set column2 = replace(column1, 'a', 'L');
```

> column1 = ab1 
>   column2 = Lb1

The second update:

```
update my_table set column2 = replace(column1, 'b', 'L');
```

> column1 = ab1 
>   column2 = aL1

The third update:

```
update my_table set column2 = replace(column1, '1', 'N');
```

> column1 = ab1 
>   column2 = abN

So because you never change `column1` you will always take the "latest version" and update it. So how to fix this. One way which is not nice is like this:

```
update my_table set column2 = 
  replace(
          replace(
                replace(column1, 'a', 'L'),
          'b', 'L'), 
  '1', 'N');
```

> column1 = ab1 
>   column2 = LLN

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try your code and see what it returns:)